# Create and handle my own events in Javascript

Tags: javascript, events, decision-tree

this is a general question.
Is there any API, framework, library or pattern that allows me to create and handle events in JavaScript?
I'm building a decision tree based in events and actions. Event aren't going to come just from the DOM but also from external devices as a kinect or some others sensors. I need to be able to dispatch an action when I track something in particular with the kinect, for exemple.

Comment: Do a search for *"javascript observable"*

Answer (score 2):

Javascript supports this natively:

[Creating and triggering events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)